# Job Shop : Arena

Tags: simulation, jobs

I'll try and keep it simple : I've started using **Arena Simulation** for studies purposes, and up until now, I've been unable to find any conclusive documentation or tutorial as to **how to create a Job Shop**, if you could direct me to **specific and practical** documentation, or otherwise a helpful example which could get me started , that would be most helpful.

My problem : A given number of jobs must be processed through a given number of ressources (machines), each job has a different route to take, and each one has a different work-time depending on the resource it is using.

**Ex** : For job_1 to be finished, it must first use ressource_1 with 5 seconds execution-time, then ressource_3 with 3 seconds execution-time and finally ressource_9 with 1 second execution-time. Of course, a different job has a totally different route and different execution-times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an MS thesis I found...

http://www.scribd.com/doc/54342479/Simulation-of-Job-Shop-using-Arena-Mini-Project-Report

ADDENDUM:

The basic idea is to use ASSIGN to label the jobs with attribute variables reflecting their routing requirements.  Those attributes can be read and used by decision blocks to route the job to the appropriate next workstation or to the exit.  Perhaps [these notes](http://nsl.pnu.edu/lecture/MAutomation/simulation06.pdf) will be more useful to you than the MS thesis cited above.  That's about all I can give you since I haven't used Arena for several years now -- I no longer have access to it and can't put together any specific examples.

Comment: @Unforgiven - Then you'll need to be more specific about what you're looking for.

Comment: How to define start-time, processing-time and due date for each job and for each machine